# How to turn off the auto scrolling feature in IBM DOORS?

Tags: websphere, ibm-doors

I use DOORs regularly, however, on a module that is rather large in size the auto scrolling feature takes 5 mins to scroll up and down the module to find its matching link within the other module I have open.

For example: Window A (module 1) & Window B (module 2)

I have Module 1 open on the left and module 2 open on the right. I am scrolling through module 2 to find the info I am looking for and at the same time module 1 is auto scrolling to keep up with matching the information that is linked.

This causing the SW to crash, freeze, take forever to scroll and lock me out etc.

Does anyone know of a way to turn this off? so I can freely use IBM DOORs without the auto scroll/auto match feature?

I have looked through all the setting within DOORs and have not found anything pertaining to this.

Comment: perhaps you can share a screenshot? I have never seen such an auto scroll mechanism when two (independent) module explorer windows are open

Comment: I cannot share a screenshot, it is all confidential information. Both the modules are linked together, one being the parent and the other being the child so to speak. When you scroll on the child module, the parent module tries to keep up and find the appropriate row associated with the child module. It slows down the whole sw and sometimes crashes all together.

Comment: you can use tools like Greenshot to create a screenshot and to anonymize the visible text. Are we talking about DOORS or DOORS Next?